# Named pipes application that used to work suddenly fails with timeout

Tags: wcf, named-pipes

I have a WCF Service application that successfully ran for a long time.

Since a couple of days, all client calls fails with a **timeout**. I checked using step by step debugging that and the server method never runs although the connection is opened correctly on the client side.

The **server part** is:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Server.ClientSession));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Contract.IEngine),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None)
    {
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000
    }, "net.pipe://Engine");

    host.Open();
```

The **client part**:

```
engine = new EngineClient(
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None)
    { 
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact, 
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000 
    },
    new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://Engine"));

engine.Actions.Subscribe(); // <= Fails with TIMEOUT
```

Where `EngineClient` class is a wrapper around `ClientBase<>`:

```
public class EngineClient : ClientBase<IEngine>
{
    public EngineClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)
        : base(binding, address)
    {
    }

    public IEngine Actions
    {
        get
        {
            return Channel;
        }
    }
}
```

As explained, this worked for months and broke suddenly for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

Another new WCF service under tests is running on the same machine for a couple of day. It also used a named pipe communication on a different address, but the server code missed the `HostNameComparisonMode` parameter.

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(OtherServer.ClientSession));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(OtherContract.IEngine),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None) 
    {
        /* THE LINE BELOW WAS MISSING */
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact,

        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000
    }, "net.pipe://OtherEngine");

    host.Open();
```

I suppose that this service was conflicting with the other client calls. Now as the `HostNameComparisonMode` has been correctly set on this new Service, everything is working fine.